# How to update a RadioGroup in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-radiogroup

**Aim**

Every X seconds the assignment and possible answers need to be updated.

**Attempt**

Possible answers were added to the Android app using `ll.addView(radioGroupPossibleAnswers(params3));`.

The idea was that calling `radioGroupPossibleAnswers(params3);` within the update thread would update the possible answers within the radio group like this works for the assignment by calling `textView2.setText("" + assignment.getAssignment() + "");`.

*UpdateThread*

```
assignment.setRandomIntegerOneAndTwo(10);

assignmentTextView.setText("" + assignment.getAssignment() + "");

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

relativeLayout.addView(assignmentTextView);
relativeLayout.addView(radioGroupPossibleAnswers(radioGroupLayoutParams));

setContentView(relativeLayout);

Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tenSecondCountDown(countDownTextView);
                        assignment.setRandomIntegerOneAndTwo(10);

                        assignmentTextView.setText(""
                                + assignment.getAssignment() + "");

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                        radioGroupPossibleAnswers(params3);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

*RadioGroup*

```
private RadioGroup radioGroupPossibleAnswers(
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p) {
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    rg.setLayoutParams(p);
    ArrayList<Integer> a = assignment.getPossibleAnswers();
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < assignment.getPossibleAnswers().size(); i++) {
        int possibleAnswer = a.get(i);

        System.out.println("Possible answer: " + a.get(i));

        rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        rb[i].setText(a + " " + assignment.getPossibleAnswers().size()
                + " " + i + " " + possibleAnswer);
        rb[i].setId(i);
        rb[i].setTextSize(30);

        rg.addView(rb[i]);
    }
    return rg;
}
```

**Result**

Although the assignment updates and the `radioGroupPossibleAnswers` is called every 10 seconds (figure 1) and the possible answers update (figure 2), the possible answers remain the same.

[image: figure 1]

**Figure 1:** the `radioGroupPossibleAnswers` is called every ten seconds

[image: figure 2]

**Figure 2:** the possible answers are updated every ten seconds

Comment: try to debug and check..

Comment: @MeenalSharma according the logCat info logging the method is called every ten seconds

Comment: it is beacause everytime when you call radioGroupPossibleAnswers  method..the loop starts from i=0..thats why it shows the same value again and again..

Comment: @MeenalSharma A new assignment is set using `assignment.setRandomIntegerOneAndTwo(10);` before calling the method and the @number changes within `10-19 15:37:03.875: I/System.out(4504): CP2: android.widget.RadioGroup@42622920` every 10 seconds.

Comment: try to debug and see each line of your method..and see what value you are getting..

Comment: @MeenalSharma the possible answers are updated every ten seconds according the LogCat

Comment: you are nt adding rg in your layout view

Comment: @MeenalSharma The RadioGroup is added using `relativeLayout.addView(radioGroupPossibleAnswers(radioGroupLayoutParams));` and displayed, but cannot be updated subsequently by specifying `radioGroupPossibleAnswers(params3);` within the thread

Comment: @MeenalSharma Calling `ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = assignment.getPossibleAnswers();` again within `possibleAnswersRadioGroup(RadioGroup radioGroup,
   RadioButton[] radioButton)` method solved the issue. Thank you for the advices. Perhaps you could post an answer which can be accepted.

Comment: glad u got the solution